# sysbase 0 workerprocess

Tags: sap-ase

I'm trying to analyse the output of sp_sysmon , the problem is that the number of worker process is null
here is the query :

```
sp_sysmon begin_sample
go
select top 1000 * from BEVENTS 
go
sp_sysmon end_sample, wpm
```

and this is the output :

```
 Worker Process Requests
   Total Requests                     0.0           0.0           0       n/a   

 Worker Process Usage
   Total Used                         0.0           0.0           0       n/a   
   Max Ever Used During Sample        0.0           0.0           0       n/a   

 Memory Requests for Worker Processes
   Total Requests                     0.0           0.0           0       n/a
```

Comment: I just ran the same commands, and recieved the same output.  It appears as that a basic select statement does not spawn extra workers, so that section comes out blank.  It might help to find out what you are looking for, so we can better assist you.

Comment: thanks i wanna just verify if this results are weird or normal

Answer (score 0):

Having 0 Worker Process Requests in itself isn't a problem. But if you want to see them, run a dbcc checkstorage during the sp_sysmon run.